# Is there a way of getting a diagram of what calls what?

Tags: delphi, diagram

For Delphi 2010, is there a way to get a diagram, starting with function X (or even the whole program), of what other functions/procedures are called...

Something along the lines of:

```
Function X
  - Function A
    - Procedure B
    - Procedure C
  - Function D
```

(Of course graphical would be nicer...)

Comment: Related but different; Delphi Enterprise/Architect UML features contain support for Sequence Diagrams.  Not exactly what you're asking for, I suspect, but related. sequence diagram example from another tool is here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html

Comment: Looking at this 2 years later, I wish that the OP had indicated whether he is looking for static or dynamic call tree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Peganza Pascal Analyzer](http://peganza.com/#PAL) offers both [call tree](http://peganza.com/PALHelp/index.html?cross_reference_report.htm) and [reverse call tree](http://peganza.com/PALHelp/index.html?cross_reference_report.htm) reports. There are a number of other static code analyzers available, but this is the one I am familiar with.

So far as I know, there is nothing of this nature built in to Delphi.

Comment: AQTime (which is included with Delphi now I think) will show you the call tree of a particular code run.

Comment: AQTime does both static and dynamic analysis, and Peganza PAL does only static analysis.  AQTime has more of a graphical display, whereas the Peganza output is text, which you could output as flat text or xml, and then build yourself a chart.  PAL can't find a great many of the real world chains of calls that occur dynamically, such as event callbacks, or even cases where derived classes that override virtual methods, which then call other things not called by the base class method, etc.   For that, dynamic analysis would be required.

Comment: Incidentally, I still recommend buying PAL because it's CHEAP like Borscht, and it's got a tonne of great "code hygiene" features, like a "Lint tool" for pascal. Costs less than $200 US.  Much cheaper than AQTime.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of an AQTime call chart. AQTime's call sequences can be gathered either dynamically (gathered from a running program) that means you have to activate the code path you want to chart (make sure some menu or button you can click in the UI calls this code) and then you can chart it, or they can be gathered statically.  The dynamic one might seem like more work, and you might think that static analysis is better, and in some ways static analysis is better, but dynamic call sequence charts are actually "what really happened in one particular run" whereas static analysis provides "what the parser could figure out to be always true, whether or not this code path even gets run by you, or your customer at all".  In fact, I recommend using both paths, and comparing them to see what you learn.

[image]

[AQTime pro](http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/performance-profiling/) is quite expensive, but I am unaware of any free alternatives. (No I don't work for SmartBear, or Embarcadero.).  I am a professional developer, and I find that such tools are worth the price.  Your call.

I usually use the call sequence feature **while running** from the performance profiler, so that I get some Time values (the digram below shows `Time: #.## msec` because the data was gathered by the performance profiler, dynamically, rather than by the static analysis profiler, which doesn't know how long a function takes to execute).

Answer (score 2):

[IDA Pro can do that for you](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml). . (for any program, not only delphi progs)

Answer (score 2):

[Code Visual to Flowchart](http://www.fatesoft.com/s2f/) (FateSoft) is also nice and of good help.